# Can 18psi water source run a 20" Big Blue Sediment filter without pump?

Tags: filter

My water pressure is 18psi from source. It is sufficient water even for bathing in second floor. What will happen if I'd put say 1, 2 or 3 pc. 20" Big Blue sediment filter in the water line? What will happen to my 18psi pressure? Will it turn it to 15psi or maybe 10psi?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which model and what rate of flow you are using at the time.  The manufacturer's spec sheet has the details:

[Big Blue Filter Specs](https://www.pentair.com/content/dam/extranet/pentek/filtration/spec-sheets/english/310053-pentek-big-blue-spec-sheet.pdf)

See the section titled

> SPECIFICATIONS AND PERFORMANCE

In the table there look at the right-hand column for INITIAL ∆P.  Also refer to the graph:  PRESSURE DROP VS FLOW RATE

EDIT:

In your comment you said:

> My point is. Compared to with and without any filter. The flow rate
> can change due to changing in pressure via the filter, right? This is
> my original question not directly answeree

No, you asked about pressure not flow rate.  Specifically you asked:

> What will happen to my 18psi pressure? Will it turn it to 15psi or
> maybe 10psi?

This is answered by the specs from the filter manufacturer.  This does not address flow rate as that is NOT determined by the filter.

To specifically answer the questions you raised in your post as well as the question you asked in your comments:

1. The PRESSURE will drop because of the insertion of any filter.  How much depends on the filter, its condition, the flow rate, and other factors.
2. The FLOW is determined by the source (i.e. the pump or the municipal supply) and is not directly affected by the filter.

Check the specs on your pump (assuming you have a pump as you didn't say) and you will see graphs such as this one that show how the pump's flow is affected by the pressure (i.e. the "head").

[Sample Flow vs. Head Graph](https://images.app.goo.gl/usb9UH5WjSsa2MQE7)

In other words, it depends.

Comment: What does INITIAL ∆P in the document mean?

Comment: INITIAL ∆P is the amount of pressure in psi that drops across the filter when you first start the flow.  The graph below then lets you calculate the steady-state based on filter model and flow rate.

Comment: And it (pressure differential) will get larger (for the same flow rate) as the media clogs.

Comment: What if my pump is 1 horsepower with 20 gallon per minute flow rate. Will the filter also be 20 gallon per minute? Can filter attenuate the flow rate of source flow rate?

Comment: Don't confuse the pump's capacity with the actual flow rate at the time.  That's generally going to depend on the point(s) of use.  If you open a tap and it flows 2 gallons/minute, that's all the pump is going to deliver and that's going to be your figure for pressure loss through the filter.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if needed, you can use more than one filter in parallel to reduce the pressure drop across them.  For example if you have two filters in parallel with 5 gal/min. flowing, the effective drop will be at the 2.5 gal/min rate from the graph.

Comment: Do you have data for the 20" long slim filters (2.5" diameter sediment filters instead of 4.5" diameter). Id like to see the pressure loss against flow rate graph. Also did you mean flow rate cant be attenuated in the sediment filters from sources but only pressure?

Comment: flow and pressure are two different things.  You cannot attenuate flow since water is an incompressible fluid.  Namely if you put 1 gal/minute into the system you must get 1 gal/min out, barring leaks of course.  The problem is that in a real-world system, blockage will increase pressure which may impact flow.  If you need data for other filters, I believe you'll find them on the manuf. web sites.

Comment: I mean the water has to cross via many particles in the inside of the filter. Remember way back when it takes 3 minutes just to get a glass of water in the old filter. Is this not the same in sediment filters?

Comment: My point is. Compared to with and without any filter. The flow rate can change due to changing in pressure via the filter, right? This is my original question not directly answeree